# How should I Level Up and Get More Powerful Items in Realm of the Mad God?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I am level 16, and I want to level up faster by getting closer to the middle of my map. How can I tell the direction to the middle and the godlands, and what is the best way for me to get better items? Right now all of my gear is trash. I would appreciate your help greatly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply reccomend looking on your map for yellow dots in the vague direction away from the beach. Once hovering over that if theres a cluster of lvl 20s, just teleport. If your trying to not teleport for fame bonus just walk away from the beach and follow class quests.